# Regex Issue in Javascript escape special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

```
validateName = function (str) {
               if (((/[!@#$%^&*()_+=-`~,.<>;':"\/\[\]\|{}(_+]/)).test(str)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (str.length <= 2 || str.length >= 19) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Hi,In the above regex i am trying to accept a name which is between 3 to 20 characters and it should not have any of the special characters,it can have alphanumeric characters.
The Problem is it is Disallowing me to use Capital Letters.
Also it Can Accept Words in Any language.
Thanks.

Comment: replace that complex regex with simply `/\W+/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include all characters that you want from other languages, otherwise below regex will suffice

```
var regex = /[^\w\s]+/;
```

example

```
validateName = function (str) {
    var regex = /[^\w\s]+/;
    if (regex.test(str) || str.length <= 2 || str.length >= 19 ) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: remember the usage of `\s` it is for white spaces, names can contain white spaces

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace your method with

```
validateName = function (str) {
    if ( (/\W+/).test(str) || str.length <= 2 || str.length >= 19 ) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

`\W+` checks for all special characters.